# Not returning the jsx component with this function written inside class

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

It's not returning the jsx component with this function written inside class

I think that I have some understanding error about writing this code structure

Is there any mistake?

```
renderDonePage = () => {
  return(
  this.state.loaded ?

    <div style={{ padding: '10px',margin: 30, borderRadius: 8 }}>
    <Row gutter={8}>
          <Card title="Cart Items">
          <Col span={16}>
            {this.renderImage()}
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
            {this.renderBoxContent()}
        </Col>
      </Card>
    </Row>
  </div>
:

 <div style={{textAlign:'center',alignItems:'center',verticalAlign:'middle'}} >
  <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
</div>
  )}
```

Should able to display and return the structure

Answer (score 1):

The this.state.loaded should not appear within the jsx you are returning

```
RenderDonePage = () => {
    return this.state.loaded ? (

    <div style={{ padding: '10px',margin: 30, borderRadius: 8 }}>
    <Row gutter={8}>
          <Card title="Cart Items">
          <Col span={16}>
            {this.renderImage()}
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
            {this.renderBoxContent()}
        </Col>
      </Card>
    </Row>
  </div>
) : (

 <div style={{textAlign:'center',alignItems:'center',verticalAlign:'middle'}} >
  <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
</div>
  )}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, Thank you for that!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is fine, if you can not display the structure you want, maybe there are errors happen inside these functions. Check the console in dev tool to see if any error message show up.

```
renderImage()
renderBoxContent()
```